# Shiny & ggvis select subset of data dynamically

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

how can I select a subset of the data and plot it using `shiny` & `ggvis`?
As the ggvis [documentation](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html) states, it is not possible to swap the dataset using `ggvis` `input_select`. Besides this limitation it would be awesome if the data preprocessing & filtering would have to be performed only once.
This is my try using `selectInput()`. I want to be able to choose parts or the whole dataset for display

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)


set.seed(1233)
cocaine <- cocaine[sample(1:nrow(cocaine), 500), ]

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Select", append("Give me all!", as.list(sort(unique(cocaine$state)))))
  })

    if(input$dataset != "Give me all!"){
     a <- filter(rawData, cocaine$state == input$dataset)
  }
  if(input$dataset == "Give me all!"){
     a <- cocaine
  }
  a$id <- 1:nrow(a)
  return(a)

    datFiltered %>%
    ggvis(~weight, ~price, key := ~id) %>%
    bind_shiny("plot1") # Very important!
})
```

Here is the UI

```
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
  ggvisOutput("plot1")
  ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a few problems and doesn't run... why are you returning from the main server function? And you're using two variables `dataFiltered` and `rawData` that aren't defined anywhere.

Here is the solution of what you're trying to do

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
    ggvisOutput("plot1")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
      selectInput("dataset", "Select", append("Give me all!", as.list(sort(unique(cocaine$state)))))
    })

    observeEvent(input$dataset, {
      if(input$dataset == "Give me all!"){
        data <- cocaine
      } else {
        data <- filter(cocaine, cocaine$state == input$dataset)
      }
      data$id <- seq(nrow(data))

      data %>%
        ggvis(~weight, ~price, key := ~id) %>%
        layer_points() %>%
        bind_shiny("plot1") 
    })


  }
))
```

Please try to post code that can be run or at least make in the code saying what doesn't run or what variables need to be defined etc :)

Answer (score 2):

@daattali - I have a suggested improvement to your solution.  You use filter in the observeEvent, which introduces NA's to the solution and causes the event to fire incorrectly.  Instead, use subset as shown below:

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
    ggvisOutput("plot1")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
      selectInput("dataset", "Select", append("Give me all!", as.list(sort(unique(cocaine$state)))))
    })

    observeEvent(input$dataset, {
      if(input$dataset == "Give me all!"){
        data <- cocaine
      } else {
        data <- subset(cocaine, cocaine$state == input$dataset)
      }
      data$id <- seq(nrow(data))

      data %>%
        ggvis(~weight, ~price, key := ~id) %>%
        layer_points() %>%
        bind_shiny("plot1")
    })


  }
))
```